# Strange exception consuming JSON from Android application

Tags: java, android, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I created an Android application that consumes and parsing a JSON

In my development environment that JSON is:
http://balonmanoblog.hkadejo.com/ge/...v1/categorias/
and everything works fine

But in my production environment, change the direction of JSON is as follows:
http://www.balonmanoblog.com/ge/inde...v1/categorias/
but no longer works

```
07-09 09:17:37.390: WARN/System.err(7247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error 
07-09 09:17:37.390: WARN/System.err(7247):     at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ByteSourceBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceBootstrapper.java:155) 
07-09 09:17:37.390: WARN/System.err(7247):     at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ByteSourceBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceBootstrapper.java:197)
```

Wrong? Help me please.

thanks

Comment: Could you please post unshortened URLs to your JSON data?

Comment: http://www.balonmanoblog.com/ge/index.php/api/v1/categorias/

Comment: Please close/remove or shed some light on the cause of this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code path suggest that something went wrong during encoding detection; but to reproduce it it would be necessary to get actual document bytes. If you could first read content into a byte array (use ByteArrayOutputStream), it would be easier to know what parser sees.
Error message does not give enough information, but suggest that this is somehow invalid state, i.e. it could be a bug in parser's encoding handling.